# How to regain access to billing account after migration to Google Identity and organization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity, google-cloud-billing

I had a Google Cloud project which I used with a "private" account user@mycompany.com. I wanted to allow my colleagues to the project, too, so I created an organiatzion mycompany.com for Google Identiy.

I wanted to re-use user@mycompany.com and had to delete it because it was a private account and thus blocked for Google Identity as far as I understand. In order to delete it, I switched ownership of the CCP project over to another private account other@mycompany.com.

Then I created the organization mycompany.com and moved the GCP project under its root. Everything runs smoothly, except I can no longer access the billing account which is still associated with the GCP project. I need access to it to download the invoice for the accounting department in my company.

I could replace the account with a new one and it'd be nice if it was configured in the organization rather than associated with a specific account. However, the invoice would probably lost and the accounting team would be in trouble as would I.

I can't use the GCP billing chat support because the first message I get is ~"you're not the admin of the project's billing account" without further options.

The GCP is still using the billing account and the ID is shown.

Comment: 1) Are you still able to log in to Google Accounts with the billing account email address? https://accounts.google.com/ 2) If yes, add the email address to the ORG's IAM. Then you can grant your new email address billing roles to the billing account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow cannot answer customer support questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745). Please consider contacting the company support with your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You can create a ticket to the [GCP Account and Resource Recovery Request](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_access_recovery) team by following this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_access_recovery)

Besides chat, Google offers [alternative options to contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#alternative_options_to_contact_support) in case this escenario happen to you again. There is a [Support Contact Troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/9664343) page that will ask you some questions to define the best path of actions based on your escenario.

I followed the [Support Contact Troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/9664343) to find out that you could contact the [GCP Account and Resource Recovery Request](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_access_recovery) to file a ticket with Support.

The form can be used only under the following conditions:

- You no longer have access to a GCP Project or Billing Account which you previously had access to.  You must be able to identify the resource, to which you are trying to regain access.
- There are no other resource administrators or Organization administrators who have access to the Project or Billing Account in question. (If there are, you must contact these individuals).
- Your account is in good standing and has not been suspended.

The form will ask for your name, email address, Billing Account ID or Project ID and a brief description of how or why you have lost access.